# Is there an idiomatic way to convert empty Vec to None?

Tags: rust

I have a closure in a [`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) that ends in this if statement:

```
if my_vec.is_empty() {
    None
} else {
    Some(my_vec)
}
```

Is there a simple way to convert an empty `Vec` into either a `None` or a `Some(my_vec)`?

Comment: Not that I know of. Is there a reason you want this? Personally I'd usually use a 0 length vec to indicate an absence of values.

Comment: [relevant](http://www.thecodelesscode.com/case/6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned `filter_map`, what about changing

```
sth.filter_map(|item| {
  let my_vec = some_operation(item);
  if my_vec.is_empty() {
    None
  } else {
    Some(my_vec)
  }
})
```

to

```
sth
.map(|item| some_operation(item))
.filter( |vec| !vec.is_empty())
```

According to official doc, Rust's iterators are zero-cost abstraction, so you can do this without extra cost.

Answer (score 9):

There is a function in `impl bool` called `then` which converts a bool to an option.

```
let opt = (!my_vec.is_empty()).then(|| my_vec);
```

There is also `then_some`, available in nightly.

```
#![feature(bool_to_option)] 
fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec<i32> = vec![];
    let _opt = (!my_vec.is_empty()).then_some(my_vec);
}
```